# Correct grammar: design, or are designing

Tags: verbs

I'm writing my thesis but am not sure what the correct grammar is in the following sentence and why it is the correct grammar:

> People that **are designing** something.

or

> People that **design** something.

Comment: Both are grammatical, but they mean different things. We cannot answer which is preferable in your case without knowing what your case is.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try to explain what I mean.
The full sentence I use is "The people that (are designing)/(design) something have to follow a list of requirements."
In my eyes there is no difference in the two ways of writing, but I am guessing that the first describes an ongoing activity while the second one describes it more as an activity which could be finished, ongoing, or not yet started?

Comment: Are you talking about people who design things in general, or are you talking about a specific set of people who are currently in the process of designing something?

Comment: @PeterShor I am talking about a particular set of people (designers) who design things in general.

Comment: I'm not comfortable with your use of the word "that" instead of the word "who."  Here is my suggestion: "The people who are . . .  designing something have to follow a list of requirements." "Designing" implies they are in the process of working on a project which has not yet been completed. On the other hand, "The people who design . . ." is a locution which describes generically what designers do, and no particular (unfinished) project is referenced.

Comment: Thank you! And I changed "that" to "who", I agree that it sounds better:)

Comment: If you prefer _who_ to _that_, fine: it's your preference. But there is absolutely nothing wrong with _that_ there.

Answer (score 2):

In most cases, the simple present is used for general statements, not for particular, present ones.

So "People that design something" means "people who regularly, or habitually, or as their job, design something".

"People that are designing something" means "people who, at the particular time we are referring to, are in the process of designing something".